# TabHost not rendering image on Nexus 7 but every other device

Tags: java, android, android-tabhost

I want to display a View in my TabHost thanks to TabSpec, it does work on all my devices exept the Nexus 7.

```
Drawable img = getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.tab_info_icon);
Intent intent = new Intent(context, Actus.class);
setupTab(img, intent);

private void setupTab(final Drawable image, final Intent intent) {
    View tabview = createTabView(mTabHost.getContext(),image, intent);
    TabSpec setContent = mTabHost.newTabSpec("").setIndicator(tabview).setContent(intent);
    mTabHost.addTab(setContent);
}  

private static View createTabView(final Context context, final Drawable image,final Intent intent) {  
    View view = LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.onglet, null);  

    LinearLayout ll = (LinearLayout)view.findViewById(R.id.fondOnglet);
    ll.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.tab_bg);

    ImageView iv = (ImageView)view.findViewById(R.id.imgOnglet);
    iv.setImageDrawable(image);
    return view;
}
```

R.drawable.tab_info_icon is an xml selector.

Comment: I've also had loads of weird bugs where things haven't shown up as intended on my Nexus 7 but all other devices I tried, it worked normally! So frustrating!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is strange, but the Nexus 7 is not hdpi or xhdpi, it's tvdpi, so i created a drawable-tvdpi directory and put my images there, and it works.